# How to define a range in a case statement?

Tags: excel, vba, syntax

I want to delete a column if a cell within a range (in this case the very first row) contains a specific value. I thought I could do it like this:

```
Public Sub Delete_Column()

Select Case Range(A1:A10)

Case "Birthday", "Gender"
        cell.EntireColumn.Delete

    End Select
End Sub
```

But it's not working. I'm sure it's the `Select Case Range(A1:A10)` line that's wrong, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Be a little more specific What error are you getting?
Why you need to give it a range of ```Range(A1:A10)``` if you're only checking the first cell anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Delete Columns (Using `Union`)

```vb
Sub DeleteColumns()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim drg As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    
    ' First 10 cells (columns) in the first worksheet row.
    For Each cell In ws.Range("A1").Resize(, 10).Cells
    ' Specified single-row range in the first worksheet row.
    'For Each cell In ws.Range("A1:J1").Cells
        Select Case CStr(cell.Value)
            Case "Birthday", "Gender"
                If drg Is Nothing Then
                    Set drg = cell
                Else
                    Set drg = Union(drg, cell)
                End If
            'Case Else ' do nothing
        End Select
    Next cell
    
    If drg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no cell found
    
    drg.EntireColumn.Delete
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

`Range("A1:A10")` is not a first row, it's the column A for the first row.
Perhaps you mean `Range("A1:J1")` ?

Try the modified code below:

```
Public Sub Delete_Column()

Dim Rng As Range, C As Range

' set the Range object
Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10") ' <-- replace "Sheet1" with your sheet's name

' first row should be:
Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:J1") ' <-- replace "Sheet1" with your sheet's name


' loop over each cell in your Range
For Each C In Rng.Cells
    Select Case C.Value
        Case "Birthday", "Gender"
            C.EntireColumn.Delete

    End Select

Next C

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, yes, you were right. I accidentally copied the code with the range from another worksheet. I used your code and everything is working well, except for some reason the code only deletes the first case. When I run the macro again, it runs the second case, and so on. Could I be missing something?

Comment: When deleting objects (columns) you need to loop backwards

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you're looking for.
Note use of the Range.Find method:

```
Public Sub Delete_Column()
Dim rng As Excel.Range, searchValue As Variant
    Set rng = Range("A1:A10")
    searchValue = "q"
    If Not rng.Find(searchValue, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "found"
    Else
        Debug.Print "not found"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you could:

- hide "valid" columns
- delete visible (-> "invalid") ones

  ```
   Sub DeleteColumns()

       With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:J1")

           Dim cel As Range
               For Each cel In .Cells
                   Select Case cel.Value
                       Case "Birthday", "Gender"
                       Case Else
                           cel.EntireColumn.Hidden = True ' hide "valid" columns
                   End Select
               Next

               On Error Resume Next ' ignore any error should no columns have been hidden
               .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireColumn.Delete ' delete hidden columns

               .EntireColumn.Hidden = False ' make all "valid" columns back visible

       End With

   End Sub
  ```